# What is wrong with timezone conversion?

Tags: php, timezone

I have a date in Europe/Vienna timezone:

```
2014-10-25 08:30:00
```

Which converts in Pacific/Midway timezone to:

```
2014-10-24 19:30:00
```

When i step one day forward the converted hour changes:
Europe/Vienna

```
2014-10-26 08:30:00
```

Pacific/Midway

```
2014-10-25 20:30:00
```

What causes this difference?

Code to reproduce it:

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-10-25 08:30:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Vienna'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Midway'));
var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$date = new DateTime('2014-10-26 08:30:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Vienna'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Midway'));
var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Comment: Most likely daylight saving time.. What's your code to step? Show us some more code aswell, so we can guess better..

Comment: The problem is that it is over DST change

Comment: DST started on Sunday 09 March 2014, 02:00 local standard time (PST)
DST ends on Sunday 02 November 2014, 02:00 local daylight time (PDT)

Comment: If I recall correctly, DST ended on 25-26 october... But show us some more code.. Because we won't be able to pinpoint your problem unless we see some more code..

Comment: It's DST related.. Since in vienne the hours changes with 1 hour, but not in Pacific/Midway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is Daylight saving time related:

In Europe/Vienna, the hour is reduced on the night of the 25th and 26th october. Which means that in that night there is 1 extra hour.. Because there is 1 extra hour in the Europe/Vienna timezone, It will also be 1 hour later for the Pacific/Midway timezone..

If you take the hour 07:30 Europe/Vienna, you will get the same results as your original..

The timedifference between Europe/Vienna and Pacific/Midway = 13 hours.

So in the first case 2014-10-25 08:30 - 13hrs == 2014-10-24 19:30.

For the 25th= 2014-10-26 8:30 - 13hrs == 2014-10-25 19:30.

**BUT** because Europe/Vienna has DST on the night of 25th and 26th October, you have to add 1 hour.. So thats why it's 2014-10-25 20:30

I hope it's clear to you now?